# Citation - I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry

Tags: bibtex

What is wrong with this citation please? I use BibTex and TexMaker

Error is:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: prace.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: titulka.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: uvod.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: kap00.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: kap01.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: kap02.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: kap03.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: kap04.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: kap05.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: diskuze.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: zaver.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: literatura.aux
The style file: czplainnat.bst
Database file #1: literatura.bib
Repeated entry---line 514 of file literatura.bib:
@article{Leone2010 : ,
    I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry

(There was 1 error message)    
Process exited with error(s)
```

for the entry

```
@article{Leone2010,
    author = {Leone, F. and Bohlender, D. A. and Bolton, C. T. and Buemi, C. and Catanzaro, G. and Hill, G. M. and Stift, M. J.},
    title = {The magnetic field and circumstellar environment of the helium-strong star HD 36485 ={$\delta$} Ori C},
    journal = {Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society},
    volume = {401},
    number = {4},
    pages = {2739-2752},
    year = {2010},
    month = {01},
    issn = {0035-8711},
    doi = {10.1111/j.1365-2966.2009.15858.x},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1365-2966.2009.15858.x},
    eprint = {http://oup.prod.sis.lan/mnras/article-pdf/401/4/2739/3929604/mnras0401-2739.pdf},
}
```

After deleting this citation, .bib flie works well.

This is in main file:

```
\bibliographystyle{czplainnat}    

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Seznam použité literatury}

\bibliography{literatura}
```

Comment: The entry `Leone2010` as posted can be compiled without problems with both BibTeX and Biber. The quoted error message looks like a simplified/digested version that an editor might show. Can you obtain the full message from the `.blg` file? You may also want to tell us whether you use BibTeX or Biber to compile your files and tell us more about the bibliography setup of you document in an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: I editted my question

Comment: Does your main bib file maybe have two entries with the same key, viz., `Leone2010`?

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of `HD 36485 ={$\delta$} Ori C`, you should probably write `{HD 36485 = $\delta$ Ori~C}`. Don't let BibTeX convert `HD`, `Ori`, and `C` to lowercase. Also, note the "tie", `~`, I inserted between `Ori` and `C`.

Comment: The error message says `Repeated entry`. That suggests you have two entries of the same name (`Leone2010`) in your `.bib` file. Check the entries and delete the duplicate entry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the issue that gave rise to the error message -- the presence of two bib entries with the same key -- was solved via comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While LaTeX and LaTeX-related software is sometimes criticised for unclear error messages, this message is fairly clear. The important bit of the message is

```
Repeated entry---line 514 of file literatura.bib:
@article{Leone2010 : ,
    I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
```

This suggests that you have more than one entry of the name `Leone2010` in your `.bib` file. Naturally BibTeX can only accept one entry of each name, otherwise it won't be able to make sense of your file.

Search your `.bib` file for `Leone2010`, compare the two (or more) entries you find and consolidate them into one (if the entries are to the same work) or give them separate names (if the entries are different works).

Then delete your temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, ...), check your citations to the affected work(s) and recompile with the full LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX cycle.

Comment: Note, BibTeX keys are case-insensitive